# Insert vba range variable in formula

Tags: vba, excel, range, formula

How can I insert a vba range variable in a formula?

For instance in the code bellow to replace sum(A1:A20) by sum('MyRange'):

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A1:A20")
Range("A21").Formula = "=sum(A1:A20)"
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `Range("A21").Formula = "=SUM(" & MyRange.Address(False, False) & ")"`

Comment: Great, I was looking for this .Address qualifier! thanks!
I don't know how to turn your comment as the answer...

Comment: You can upvote with the arrow next to my comment, or mark John Coleman's answer below

Comment: @ShaiRado You should turn your comment into the answer. I did the naïve version that included dollar signs, so I deleted it.

Comment: I am really sorry, I guess I have to few reputation to upvote, so I cannot see the button...
Also as John mentioned I cannot see the answer I now assume deleted.

Comment: @ShaiRado what does "&" do in this case?

Comment: @Moreno it `CONCATENATE` the `String`s together

Comment: @Moreno They link the strings: String1 & string2. Range.Address returns a string... Edit: Ho well... ShaiRado was faster: thank you for such dedicated support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Range.Address` property, just use:

```
Range("A21").Formula = "=SUM(" & MyRange.Address(False, False) & ")"
```